# How to represent a self call function which calls other object/entity in a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have created a sequence diagram and one of the objects will do a self function and inside of the function it will call the other class object function. How do i represent this correctly in a sequence diagram? My current diagram show it this way for now but i don't think its the right way to show it.
[image]

Comment: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html about in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The self-call can be represented with an overlapping execution specification (rectangle).  This allows to distinguish the call from the execution of the called function, and to visualize with accuracy what happens in the self-call, and what happens after the self-call returns:

[image]

Comment: One remark - the self-call arrow's head should be at the tob border of the execution specification as the call triggers it.

Comment: @Ister yes, of course, the toP border since the message starts the execution specification. This was a quick hand-made graphic.